# Python remove pure numbers only

Tags: python, integer

I have a {str}

```
[ ASD2334  234FTA  FTA123ASD  123XCV456 23445  980987]
```

I want to remove real numbers only and the resulting `output` should be

```
[ ASD2334  234FTA  FTA123ASD  123XCV456 ]
```

tried `re.sub` with several options involvind '\d' but not working out

Comment: That's not a string. It's not even a {str}. Or a list. Or Python.

Comment: it is a {str} I am giving you an example...its not the actual string...

Comment: Please give an example that is syntactically correct Python. {str} is not a Python data type and your example gives an error when pasted into the interpreter.

Comment: Do you know what a pure number is?

Comment: thats what Pycharm debugger is telling me. Let me paste the string from the watch windoe below
 raw = {str} 'NS543 in module 2876FXB performs better than 919BYS47...comment 7654'

Comment: I want the output as :
NS543 in module 2876FXB performs better than 919BYS47...comment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have positive numbers in your list code is the following

```
n = "ASD2334  234FTA  FTA123ASD  123XCV456 23445  980987"
lst = n.split(" ")


def pure_numbers(l):
  result=[]
  for i in l:
    try:
      int(i)
    except:
      result.append(i)
  return result

lst = pure_numbers(lst)
print (lst)
```

Comment: Why you don't agree with my solution. Is something else that you want to do, please explain

Comment: its not a list as i said...its {str}

Comment: a ok you you just make it a list them by adding n.split(" ")

Comment: needs to be passed on as string..... can we use something like re.sub(\d+)....the \d is for integers but its removing integers from terms like 2876FXB  . only cases like 23456   76543 etc should be removed

Comment: if you convert the list back to string again??

Comment: c'mon man thats not a valid solution...i have 10000 txt files to read from..imagine the amount of time it will add

Comment: You had to explain from the start that you need a very efficient algorith, although i don't think it will take that long

Comment: That's why you don't answer bad questions. You will get dragged down into a rabbit hole of unclear specs and demands.

Comment: if the answer is close , you could have marked it as a positive one.